# PhpMyAdmin foreign key issue - on create empty dropdown list

Tags: phpmyadmin, foreign-keys

I want to create foreign keys. On the same database, sometimes it works, sometimes not... Let us take an example:

Table1, Table2 and Table3:

[image]

When I want to creat a foreign key between Table2.date and Table1.date, it works. Also between Table3.date and Table1.date. But, between Table3.numero and Table2.numero, it doesn't work. When I want to creat it, the dropdown menu is empty :

[image]

Any idea ? Thanks !

Comment: did you add an index to the table on that field?

Comment: yes : they are underlined (primary index).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try to add the foreign key directly via SQL.

`ALTER Table3 ADD FOREIGN KEY (numero) REFERENCES Table2(numero);`

in case this is just a phpMyAdmin issue. Also all your tables should have InnoDB as engine, but think you have already done this.

Comment: Good to hear that. You could then mark the answer as accepted, which would be the Stackoverflow-way of saying thanks and will also show other users that this problem was solved ;)